# SQL Compact Edition: Unable to locate Dependency EntityFramework.Relational

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am trying to install Entity Framework for SQL Server Compact Edition in ASP.NET 5 application (MVC 6) with Visual Studio is 2015.

I have run the following command in Package Manager Console to install the SQL Server Compact 3.5

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact35 –Pre
```

The result was successful

```
Installing NuGet package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact35.7.0.0-rc1-final.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact35 7.0.0-rc1-final' to Web
```

However, restoring of packages failed

```
Restoring packages for Web\project.json
CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework.Relational'
Unable to locate Dependency EntityFramework.Relational 7.0.0-rc1-16263
Writing lock file Web\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 6789ms elapsed
Errors in Web\project.json
Unable to locate Dependency EntityFramework.Relational 7.0.0-rc1-16263
NuGet Config files used:
C:\Users\Linux\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
Feeds used:
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU
```

The application is targeting 1.0.0-rc1-update1 DNX version.

Dependencies in project.json are

```
"EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact35": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta8"'
```

Could you please advise what can be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server Compact provider requires .NET 4.5.1 or later, and does not run under .NET Core

Comment: Thank you for the answer Erik